# how to avoid multi event bind on dataTables rowCallback

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using the famous dataTables plugin, Every time that i draw rows to the table to be displayed, rowCallback adds a click handler to the row and as a result the event fires multi-times.
How can some one avoid this behaviour ?

My Callback

```
        rowCallback: function( row, data, index ) {
            $(row).on("click", function(){
                callMyMethod();
            });

            $(row).on("dblclick", function(){
            });
        },
```

Comment: How are you binding the click handler right now?

Comment: i just added in original message my Callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update the event handlers like:

```
$(row).off("click").on("click", function() {
  console.count('Clicked');
});

$(row).off("dblclick").on("dblclick", function() {
  console.count('Double Clicked');
});
```